# how to set parallax-imagescroll container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using parallax-imageScroll at this address https://github.com/pederan/Parallax-ImageScroll

Instructions say you can change the container like this:
container: $('body') The element to which the parallax image(s) will be attached to

but when I use it in my code:

```
$("#parallax").imageScroll({
    holderMaxHeight: 500,
    container: "$('#parallax')"
});
```

I get this error:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $('#parallax')

Comment: Probably due to the quotes. Try `container: $('#parallax')`

Comment: @Michel You should post that as an answer and get the credits.